# Join with last record of details table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities, c#-7.0

Please consider these two tables in my database:

Header:

```
Id                   Name
-------------------------------
1                     London
2                     Berlin
3                     Paris
```

and Details:

```
Id          HeaderId            Amount           YearMonth
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1              1                 1000             2010-01
2              1                 2000             2010-05
3              2                 3000             2015-04
4              2                 2700             2017-12
5              2                 4500             2016-10
6              2                 7000             2011-09
7              1                 3000             2009-05
```

I want Header records with related **Last** Details record. For example:

```
HeaderId              HeaderName           Amount                     
----------------------------------------------------
1                       London              2000              
2                       Berlin              2700             
3                       Paris               Null
```

I wrote this query for `Inner Join` version (But I want `Outer Join` version):

```
from h in Header
join d in Details
 on h.Id equals d.HeaderId
select new
{
        HeaderId = h.Id,
        HeaderName = h.Name,
        Amount = (Details.Where(k=>k.HeaderId == h.Id).OrderBy(m=>m.YearMonth).LastOrDefault() == null ? null : Details.Where(k=>k.HeaderId == h.Id).OrderBy(m=>m.YearMonth).LastOrDefault().Amount,
}
```

and I got this error:

> System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Details.LastOrDefault()Details' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

How can I get above result?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query should return desired result:

```cs
from h in Header
from d in Details.Where(d => d.HeaderId == h.Id)
    .OrderByDescending(d => d.YearMonth)
    .Take(1)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
select new
{
    HeaderId = h.Id,
    HeaderName = h.Name,
    Amount = d.Amount
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. It hadn't access to `h` in line: `from d in Details.Where(d => d.HeaderId == h.Id)`

Comment: You should have. It is common SelectMany query and `h` identifier should be accessible. I've done hundreds of similar queries before.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see two `from`. I'll check it

Answer (score -1):

You should change your code as :

```
 Amount = Details.Where(k=>k.HeaderId == h.Id).OrderByDescending(m => m.YearMonth).FirstOrDefault(o=>o.Amount);
```